# Div Visibility not working in Firefox, inner image not displaying

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, razor

[edit]Problem now solved

I have an edit(div with an image) button within another div that contains editable content, my plan is to have the button hidden until the cursor hovers over the content div.

My problem is that if I use `display:none;` in the CSS and then use a javascript function to show and hide the divButton again then the image does not display in FireFox.

If I use `element.style.visibility = "visible";` then FireFox doesn't show the div at all.

Any input would be really appreciated thanks :)

Relevant code:

HTML

```
<div id="c1ContentSrc" class="widgetContent editable">
    @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.column1Content))
    <div id="c1ContentEdit" class="cmsEditButton"><img src="../../Content/images/cmsEdit.png" alt="edit" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cmsEditButton{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:37px;
    right:8px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

Alternate CSS

```
.cmsEditButton{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:37px;
    right:8px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

javascript function

```
function showEditButton(id, editId) {
    if(editId.style.display == "none"){
        if (!id.isContentEditable) {
            editId.style.display = "block";
        }
    }else{
        editId.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Alternate javascript code

```
function showEditButton(id, editId) {
    if (editId.style.visibility == "hidden" || editId.style.visibility == "") {
        if (!id.isContentEditable) {
            editId.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }else{
        editId.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Function calls

```
document.getElementById("c1ContentSrc").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
       showEditButton(document.getElementById("c1ContentSrc"), document.getElementById("c1ContentEdit"))
   }, false);

document.getElementById("c1ContentSrc").addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
       showEditButton(document.getElementById("c1ContentSrc"), document.getElementById("c1ContentEdit"))
   }, false);
```

Problem has been solved now with the following change, moved the image above the razor output, it seemed to be interfering, also removed the unnecessary div

```
 <div id="c1ContentSrc" class="widgetContent editable">
    <img id="c1ContentEdit" class="cmsEditButton" title="edit" src="../../Content/images/cmsEdit.png" alt="edit" />
    @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.column1Content))
</div>
```

Comment: recreate the issue here : http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: have you got the js that calls the functions

Comment: Function calls added as requested, thought I had put them in ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using visibility; you can use

```
display:none;
display:block;
display:none !important;
style="display:none;" //inline css
```

Avoid using visibility if you are using display, You can simultaneously play with them and implement the right code...

Comment: I was using display:none; originally this is what is causing the problem, visibility was something I tried without success to avoid the image not showing problem.

Comment: if I remove the display:none; from the CSS the image displays

Comment: Show and hid the div that contains the image which I can do, sadly when the div shows the image it contains does not.

Comment: so the image disappears when div is showing...? dnt apply any js to the image i think it is no need if your not preforming any action to it..

Comment: Thanks SaurabhLP your answers made me look at the actual layout around the image, and I stumbled upon the answer, a weird one though.

The problem seems to lie with the piece of razor code before it, weather it is the something to do with razor itself or the decoded html it is retrieving from the database (maybe malformed tag somewhere, will need to check) anyway my solution was to move the image before the razor output. was gonna post the answer to close the question but I don't have enough rep ^_^